# Liquid seems to evaporate by the end of a fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am very new to fluid simulations. I have watched several YouTube videos and I understand the basics. But for some reason, my fluid seems to evaporate as time passes in my animation.

In frames 1-40 I am filling a tank and that seems to work just find. No liquid is leaking out of the container. That did happen at first but I figured it out and got things working great. There is plenty of liquid in my tank at frame 40 so I turn off the inflow.

[image: liquid coming in]

[image: plenty of liquid and no leaks]

But as the animation goes on, the liquid just vanishes.

[image: tank is draining]

[image: tank is almost empty]

I can't seem to spot any setting that tells the simulation to not evaporate the liquid, probably because it isn't named something I would recognize. So I am hoping this is a simple newbie mistake that someone can quickly point out to me.

Here is a link to the blend file: [fluid-tank.blend](https://cloud.schworak.com/s/x5y4MBfy76jdi9L)

Comment: It looks like the simulation is leaking fluid: a limitation of the simulator. There’s a ratio somewhere in the domain properties, I think it’s called the FLIP ratio, that can help with that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I was going with APIC for the simulation method because it looked smoother. So I switched to FLIP and ran experiments from 1.0 (way too spashy) down to 0.5 at 0.1 for each step I tested. The lower numbers looked nicer but no matter what, the fluid vanishes. It is as if the engine only allows the particles to live a set amount of time. I don't see any leaking. At least not that I can detect. I have switched back to APIC since it looks a lot better.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: I added a link to the blender file. I am not sure how to directly upload and attach it to this message. PS: In my tinkering, I let the fluid fill up to frame 80 rather than 40.

Comment: I have still not figured out why the liquid evaporates. I have the particles lasting longer than the animation and nothing seems to be spilling out. But still, the animation slowly looses liquid. It seems very odd. I will start a new animation from scratch and see if is something off with my container. Although, if I don't slosh the liquid back and forth it doesn't appear to evaporate (leave the tank still). It may be related to shaking the tank.